# CUDA templated function call

Tags: templates, cuda, runtime-error, runtime

This runtime error has been bothering me for two days, I tried all the possible ways to debug it, still I couldn't find what the issue is.

```
#define CUDA_RT_CALL( call ){
cudaError_t cudaStatus = call;
if ( cudaSuccess != cudaStatus )
  fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: CUDA RT call \"%s\" in line %d of file %s failed with %s (%d).\n",
  #call, __LINE__, __FILE__, cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus), cudaStatus);
}

template <typename Tkey, typename Tvalue>
void KernelDriver(Tkey * K, Tvalue * V, int N, long * h_h, long * h_p, int A){
  Tkey * d_keys_in;
  Tvalue * d_values_in;
  CUDA_RT_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_keys_in, sizeof(Tkey)*N));
  CUDA_RT_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_values_in, sizeof(Tvalue)*N));
  CUDA_RT_CALL(cudaMemcpy(d_keys_in, K, sizeof(Tkey)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
  CUDA_RT_CALL(cudaMemcpy(d_values_in, V, sizeof(Tvalue)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

  /* myKernel() */
}
```

Above code, compiles fine. However, when I run the compiled cuda program, as long as the key-value pairs is int-long, i.g.,

```
KernelDriver<int, long>((int *)key, (long *)value, n, h_histo, h_prefix, agg);
```

CUDA runtime API reports error:

```
ERROR: CUDA RT call "cudaMemcpy(d_values_in, V, sizeof(Tvalue)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)" in line 295 of file gpucode.cu failed with invalid argument (11).
```

Moreover, when the plug-in key-value pairs is int-double, i.g.,

```
KernelDriver<int, double>((int *)key, (double *)value, n, h_histo, h_prefix, agg);
```

It has no error at all, and runs perfectly fine. I have tried to print the sizeof(long) at host and device, they are both 8 bytes. Now, I have no idea what this issue is.

Comment: To diagnose a runtime error would require an [MCVE], which you have failed to provide. Please edit your question to include code which someone else could compile, run and reproduce your error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the solution by myself. Different machine has different size in byte for "long", some of machine are 4 bytes, some of are 8 bytes. Make sure they are compiled in the compiler and architecture, Otherwise, the cudaMemcpy will not be able to copy two different chunk-size of memory.